# Iframe anchor cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have access to the parent domain and the third party domain

I have to use an iframe to display some info , i'm using a full page iframe display

the parent page has several anchors that scroll to a position when a tab is clicked.  Ofc , this doesn't work within the iframe.

I was wondering what can be done so just reset the iframe content to the top of the page , when i click these tabs. So on parent site , i use my anchors and when parent page is embedded into an iframe on another domain i control , i can just have it reset to top when same tab buttons are clicked.

```
            function doScrollToNav() {
                window.scrollTo($('#nav-bloc').offset().left,$('#nav-bloc').offset().top);
            }
```

Comment: So it uses `http://www.example.com#foobar` and it does not scroll to the content?

Comment: Not enough known since page could be using script to manage scrolling and also could be loading those elements asynchronously

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or plnkr to demonstrate?

Comment: edit post to show function used to scroll to position on page

Comment: Still not really clear what it is exactly you are trying to do

Comment: When the page inside an iframe and I click on ant tab that I apply doScrollToNav , I want to force iframe to reset to top. In normal page view, this function would scroll to the divID #nav-block , but it doesn't work in iframes